# Is there a way to Unit test HTML element's value?

Tags: html, angularjs, unit-testing

I am new to angularjs ,trying to test HTML elements but can't find a way.I am using Karma and jasmine for testing.Can anyone tell me how can i test HTML element's value or text in angularjs.
Here is my controllerspec:

```
describe('myAppCtrl', function() {

    var scope, controller, httpBackend;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend) {
        scope = $rootScope;
        controller = $controller;
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    }));


    it('should show the text of element',function() {
        expect($('#testtext')).toBe('First Angular JS App');
    }); 

});
```

Comment: A unit test would not test the html, but the controller. Are you sure you are trying to perform `unit` tests?

Comment: @MotiAzu yup i am trying to test my html element's value as well

Comment: @MotiAzu your solutions i tried but It fails gives error Expected ' ' to be 'First Angular JS App'

Answer (score 0):

You are testing a jquery element against a string.
Try this instead:

```
expect($('#testtext').text()).toBe('First Angular JS App');
```

Comment: It fails gives error EXpected ' ' to be 'First Angular JS App'

Comment: @Hassan if text contents of `#testtext` are empty, of course this assertion will fail.

Comment: @hijarian its not empty <th id="testtext" colspan="2">First Angular JS App</th> this is the html

Comment: Assuming that definition of [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) hasn't changed, it should mean that your application fills those contents after the tests check them.